# Configurar tiempo de consulta en Volley?

Tags: java, android, api, volley

Estoy consumiendo un `API rest` con `Volley`, pero la respuesta se está demorando y quiero configurar un tiempo de respuesta, si en una cantidad de tiempo determinada no he recibido ningún dato, entonces quiero que se ejecute otra acción.

Este es el código con el que estoy consumiendo el servicio.

```
private void jsonObjectRequest() throws JSONException {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        T_Configuraciones_DBManager t_configuraciones_dbManager = new T_Configuraciones_DBManager(getApplicationContext());

        T_Configuraciones t_configuraciones = t_configuraciones_dbManager.ConsultarConfiguracion(Cons.CONFIGURACION_URL);


        JSONObject jsonBody = null;
        jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("Valor", dato );




        String JSON_URL =  t_configuraciones.getCon_URL() + "/BuscarProductoDescripcion";

        final JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, JSON_URL, jsonBody,

                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject  = null ;



                        JSONArray mJsonArray = null;
                        try {
                            mJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("recordset");
                            for(int i=0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                BuscarReferenciamodelo anime = new BuscarReferenciamodelo();
                                anime.setCodigo(mJsonObject.getString("CODIGO"));
                                comprobarExistencia = mJsonObject.getString("DESCRIPCION");
                                anime.setDescripcion(comprobarExistencia);
                                lstAnime.add(anime);
                            }

                            for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {


                                try {
                                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("recordset");
                                    BuscarReferenciamodelo anime = new BuscarReferenciamodelo();
                                    anime.setCodigo(jsonObject.getString("CODIGO"));
                                    anime.setDescripcion(jsonObject.getString("DESCRIPCION"));
                                    lstAnime.add(anime);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            }



                            setuprecyclerview(lstAnime);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );
```

Quiero configurar si pasados 5 segundo sin respuesta muestre un `AlertDialog`. Traté de implementar un `timer` pero no funcionó, ejecuta el código antes de intentar traer los datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar definiendo una politica en la cual defines el "Timeout".

Define una variable del tiempo que necesitas configurar, por ejemplo 5 segundos (5000 millisegundos):

```
private int  MY_TIMEOUT = 5000;
```

define de esta forma la politica:

```
getRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        MY_TIMEOUT, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```